# Doubly linked list - Delete the list from memory

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm working on a doubly linked list. Here is the code:

```
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "Node.h"


    Node* CreateNode(void *data) 
    {
        Node* nNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        nNode->data = data;
        nNode->prev = NULL;
        nNode->next = NULL;

        return nNode;
    }

    List* CreateList()
    {
        List* nList = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
        nList->head = NULL;
        nList->tail = NULL;
        nList->current = NULL;

        return nList;
    }


    void Last(List* list, void *data)
    {
        Node* nNode = CreateNode(data);

        if (list->head == NULL) 
        {
            list->head = nNode;
            return;
        }
        else if (list->head->next == NULL)
        {
            list->tail = nNode;
            list->head->next = list->tail;
            list->tail->prev = list->head;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            list->current = list->tail;
            list->tail = nNode;
            list->tail->prev = list->current;
            list->current->next = list->tail;
            return;
        }

    }


    void First(List* list, void *data)
    {
        Node* nNode = CreateNode(data);

        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            list->head = nNode;
        }
        else if (list->head->next == NULL)
        {
            list->tail = list->head;
            list->head = nNode;
            list->head->next = list->tail;
            list->tail->prev = list->head;
        }
        else
        {
            list->current = list->head;
            list->current->prev = nNode;
            list->current->prev->next = list->current;
            list->head = nNode;
        }
    }

    void BubbleSort(List* list)
    {
        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            printf("Lista jest pusta\n");
        }
        else if (list->head->next == NULL)
        {
            printf("Lista ma jeden element.\n");
        }
        else if (list->tail->prev == list->head)
        {
            if (list->head->data > list->tail->data)
            {
            
                list->current = list->tail;
                list->current->next = list->current->prev;
                list->current->prev = NULL;
                list->current->next->prev = list->current;
                list->head = list->current;
                list->tail = list->current->next;
                list->tail->next = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bool is_sorted = false;
            Node* temp = list->head;

            while (is_sorted != true)
            {
                is_sorted = true;
                temp = list->head;

                while (temp->next != NULL)
                {
                    if (*((int*)temp->next->data) < *((int*)temp->data))
                    {
                        is_sorted = false;
                        if (temp == list->head)
                        {
                        
                            temp->next->prev = NULL;
                            list->head = temp->next;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        
                            temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                        }
                     
                        temp->prev = temp->next;

                        if (temp->next == list->tail)
                        {
                    
                            temp->next = NULL;               
                            list->tail = temp;      
                        }
                        else
                        {
                    
                            temp->next = temp->next->next;
                            temp->next->prev = temp;
                        }
                    
                        temp->prev->next = temp;            
                        temp = temp->prev;
                    }
                
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
            }
        }   
    } 

void FreeList(List* list)
{
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Lista jest pusta\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temp = list->head;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            Node* next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = next;
        }
        free(list->head);
        free(list->tail);
        free(list->current);
        free(list);
    
    }


}



void Show(List* list) 
{
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Lista jest pusta\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wartosci: ");
        list->current = list->head;

        while (list->current != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", *((int*)list->current->data));
            list->current = list->current->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }


}
```

**Here is my problem!** I have to write a function that deletes everything from the memory. I've tried a number of things however every time an error occurs. I'm hopless so any clue will be helpful. Here is the code for the particular function:

```
void FreeList(List* list)
{
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Lista jest pusta\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temp = list->head;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            Node* next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = next;
        }
        free(list->head);
        free(list->tail);
        free(list->current);
        free(list);
    
    }


}
```

I hope someone will help :D

Comment: One way of figuring out what's happening is to write a `main` that creates a small list, and then instead of using `free`, use some `myFree` that prints out the address and then calls `free`. That way you'd see when any memory block is freed the second time in error.

Comment: Related, most of your algorithms are questionable, beyond the problem Barmar found. There should *never* be a time when a list head or tail is non-null, but the other is null. For an empty list they should both be null. For a single-node list both head and tail should refer to the same node, and that's node's next and prev pointers should both be null. And for anything else head should point to the first, that node's prev should be null, tail should point to the last, that nodes next should be null, and all pointers in between should be properly chained in both directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need these three calls:

```
        free(list->head);
        free(list->tail);
        free(list->current);
```

Those nodes were already freed when you looped through the list elements. In particular, `list->head` was the first value of `temp`.